# Migrating from Oracle to Netezza and trying to see what datatype differences there are

Tags: database, oracle

I am going to be working on a migration of Oracle DW to Netezza, and I need to understand if there are any major "gotchas" with data types, etc.

Comment: Out of interest, what's driving the migration? Features or Cost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should not be major gotchas unless you have object types or Spatial objects in Oracle
Check few docs below, you might find it useful:

http://www.wisdomforce.com/resources/docs/OracleToNetezzaWithFastReader.pdf

Answer (score 1):

This Wisdomforce tool is pricey, has too many restrictions, and requires DBA access to the source database.

We just completed a project extracting huge amount of data (in TB) from Oracle to Netezza every night. We are using DBCrane, which is much easier to use.

http://www.bronzeage.us/downloads.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is one more pdf on similar subject in case need an incremental migrations based on transactions: http://www.wisdomforce.com/resources/docs/databasesync/DatabaseSyncBestPracticesforNetezza.pdf